# Text of the condolence which is given to Muhammad(saww) on the Day of Ashura?

Tags: source-identification, prophet-muhammad, shiism, translation, hussain

There is this text in religious books which has words of condolence for Muhammad(saww) upon the death of his grandson on the Day of Ashura. It's surely not the [Ziyárat of Ta`ziyah (Condolences)](http://www.duas.org/ziarattaziah.htm).

It's currently not available over the internet. [This, Text of Ashura Day Speech,](http://www.abna.ir/data.asp?lang=3&Id=131588) is the closest that could be found, but is doesn't seem to be the exact text.

What is its Arabic text and its translation?

Transliteration would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know the Arabic name for the text you are looking for?

Comment: No, I don't know.